# Compact manifolds cannot have unbounded Ricci curvature

Tags: solution-verification, riemannian-geometry

Apologies for the simple question, this is bugging me. Given any compact Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, must the Ricci curvature on $M$ be bounded? I think yes, because the Ricci curvature depends continuously on the metric and the metric is continuous, so the (operator norm of the) Ricci curvature is a continuous function on a compact set $M$ and attains its maximum.

I'm dubious because I can imagine perturbing a manifold by adding small half-Cheeger-dumbbells of decreasing radius - each one of these would be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ if the manifold is $n$-dimensional, so we could glue these diffeomorphisms together to obtain a diffeomorphism for a neighbourhood of the limit point of our sequence of dumbbells. If the dumbbells have increasing (positive or negative) curvature, then so should the whole manifold.

Comment: You are gluing an infinite sequence of dumbbells to a manifold and the result is still a manifold???

Comment: I think so. I think I still get a local diffeomorphism from my manifold to $\mathbb{R}^n$ if the dumbbells decrease in size fast enough.

Comment: The metric you propose will fail to be smooth at the limit point. The idea an upper bound on Ricci curvature is given by$$\max_{v\in SM}\operatorname{Ric}(v,v)$$which always exists because $v\mapsto\operatorname{Ric}(v,v)$ is a smooth function on the unit sphere bundle $SM$, which is compact.

Comment: The Ricci curvature of the dumbbells will go to infinity as they get smaller.

Comment: Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counterexample isn't a $C^2$ submanifold of $\mathbb{T}^3$ because the first derivative pointing towards the dumbbells isn't continuous - it changes sign on each dumbbell, but it is nonzero away from the dumbbells. In fact, the counterexample fails to be *continuously* $C^1$-differentiable. Any continuously differentiable submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be locally the graph of a continuously differentiable function (this is Theorem 1.2.1.5 in Grisvard's *Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains*). I think the counterexample is $C^1$ but not continuously $C^1$.